# Use tables from different database with different login creditionals in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have searched lot for my problem on net but could not find what I want.

The scenario is: we have two databases `DbWeb` and `DbAdmin`. I am working with `DbAdmin`. I have read-only permission on `DbWeb`. I have written a stored procedure in `DbAdmin` in which I want to add left outer join on a tables of `DbWeb`.

Both database have different login credentials. Because of these different login credentials, I can't access info from `DbWeb` into `DbAdmin`. When I tried it with same login credentials it was working. But with different login credentials I'm not able to access tables from another database.

Comment: Research **linked servers** - you can set up a link to a separate server and a database there, providing the necessary login credentials

Comment: You'll need to have a single security context that has access to both databases.  Without a login mapped to a user that exists in both databases, you can sign the proc with a certificate that exists in both databases.  See http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html